# Awk print values depending on flag

Tags: linux, sed, awk

I have a data file in the format

```
ID       Date            Sex     Age     r_val  r_flag  l_val    l_flag
0106610856   16/09/11    M   50      12.061  N       11.447  N
0107470802   09/09/11    F   64      3.146   A       4.338   A
0108490513   21/07/11    M   61      8.243   A   7.344   A
0108590534   18/08/11    M   52      4.714   A   5.106   A
0109480651   26/07/12    M   63      9.403   N   9.136   N
0110460758   21/07/11    M   64      5.643   I   4.272   I
0111290260   08/11/12    F   83      9.747   N   8.551   A
0111410339   07/02/13    M   71      4.979   A   4.482   A
```

What I wish to do is print to a new file ID, Sex, Age and Value (either r_val or l_val whenever its corresponding flag is set to N). Here is sample output for the above

```
0106610856        M      50      12.061 
0106610856        M      50      11.447         
0109480651        M      63      9.403   
0109480651        M      63      9.136   
0111290260        F      83      9.747
```

I have tried the following Awk command to achieve this: `awk '{if ($6 ~ /N/) print $1,$3,$4,$5; else if ($6 ~ /N/) print $1,$3,$4,$7}'` and get the following result

```
0106610856 M 50 12.061
0109480651 M 63 9.403
0111290260 F 83 9.747
```

I know this is the incorrect format as the if loop will not search if $8 ~/N/ if the first condition is true. Therefore my awk command picks up l_val  when the $8 condition is true only when the $6 condition is false. How do I alter my awk command to pick up both r_val and l_val if both r_flag and l_flag are set to N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use `if ..` **`else`**. in this way, you simple miss one `$6==$8=="N"` case.

try this oneliner:

```
 awk 'NR>1{if($6=="N") print $1,$3,$4,$5; if($8=="N") print $1,$3,$4,$7 } ' file
```